# why there is no relaxation method for Jacobi linear system iterative methods?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

I found that the relaxation methods for solving linear system as an iterative sequence are derived from the Gauss-Seidel method and not from the Jacobi method. I understand that the Gauss-Seidel method might look better behaved and in many cases have a smaller spectral radius than that of the Jacobi method. However, once we introduce a relaxation parameter $\omega$, things might change. Or, if they do not improve can anyone show why doing a Jacobi-based relaxation would be a bad idea? That is 
\begin{equation}
   \bf{x}_{k+1} = (\rm 1 - \omega) \bf{x}_k +  \omega \, Jacobi\_Iteration( \bf{x}_k).
\end{equation}
does not converge faster in any situation that
\begin{equation}
   \bf{x}_{k+1} = (\rm 1 - \omega) \bf{x}_k + \omega \, Gauss\_Seidel\_Iteration( \bf{x}_k) ?
\end{equation}

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the term relaxation has confused you. The weighted Jacobi exists, see e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method#Weighted_Jacobi_method but the term relaxation w.r.t. Gauss-Seidel means that the method minimizes a certain energy functional and can be viewed as a variational iterative method. 
Moreover, look here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-086-mathematical-methods-for-engineers-ii-spring-2006/readings/am62.pdf where Gilbert Strang makes a strong point about using weighted Jacobi with the weight 2/3